# Why isn't this switch exhaustive?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

If `...0` is 0 and everything before it, and `1...` is 1 and everything above, why isn't this switch exhaustive?

```
let i = 1

switch i {
case ...0: print("low")
case 1...: print("high")
}
```

The compiler is convinced I need to add a default clause.

Comment: I believe swift is only able to infer the cases are exchaustive when using an enum. It seems other data types would require a default case.

Comment: @jspcal Reading more about this, it looks like bools are now OK to switch over as well as enums, but you're right - it's just not supported!